# Boot Camp installs in wrong language. How can I fix this?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, language

I have a MacBook with an English keyboard running Lion in English. I used Boot Camp to download the WindowsSupport package and then installed 32 bit Windows 7 Ultimate, also in English.

Turns out the WindowsSupport package is in German, probably because I am currently in Switzerland.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Apple installer installs whatever language Windows' language format is set to. I am in Zurich, I set it to German Switzerland.

I had called Apple support, they didn't know that. Their theory was that because I had bought Lion in a German-language app store, it would download German Boot Camp updates.

But this is the solution.